# Jenkins Pipeline alternative for XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to create a step in my pipeline to get a Xml file and change specific elements on it (based on variables and other build outputs) before going to the next step.

Although I could easily create an C# or Java program for doing it, I decided to give it a try to add a new step in my pipeline and deal with the Xml directly.

The problem I am facing is that the `XmlSlurper` is not white-listed yet, according to these posts:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33024

  > `XmlSlurper` is too problematic and will not be supported.
  >   It is sensitive to thread context class loader issues, which can cause mysterious errors from apparently unrelated plugins. Certain methods are also inappropriate to whitelist.

Currently I have to deal with some files, and it is ok.
The [Jenkins Pipeline Utility Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) provide already some functions to read and deal with JSON already. But there is no alternative for `XmlSlurper` or anything related to that.

Unfortunately I am dealing with some tools that I can't change to JSON, and since XML is still largely used, **does someone know any alternative to `XmlSlurper`**?

*I would rather not to try do deal with those XML manually, like dealing with regex stuff.*

Answer (score 0):

Convert the XML to json in a shared library in groovy.  I have a class that resides in my shared library in src/org/config called GroovyUtils.

```
package org.config

import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json.XML
import java.util.ArrayList
import hudson.model.*;

public class GroovyUtils implements Serializable {
    def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
    def config
    def steps

    def GroovyUtils(config, steps) {
        this.config = config
        this.steps = steps
    }

    def log(msg){
        steps.println(msg)
    }

    def getFinalAttr(thingToSearchFor){
        def fileContents = new File("YourXMLFile.xml").text;
        def json = xmlToJson(fileContents);
        def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
        def foo = jsonObj["someAttr"].someArr["anotherArr"]
        def bar = foo.find { it.name == thingToSearchFor }
        return bar.finalAttr
    }

    def xmlToJson(input) {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(input)
        return xmlJSONObj.toString(2)
    }
}
```

The key method above is getFinalAttr(thingToSearchFor).

The assignments to foo and bar local variables will depend on the structure of your jsonObj but shows you that it can be traversed to get at what you want.